# How do I generate binary RFC822-style headers in Python 3.2?

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

How do I convince `email.generator.Generator` to use binary in Python 3.2? This seems like precisely the use case for the `policy` framework that was introduced in Python 3.3, but I would like my code to run in 3.2.

```
from email.parser import Parser
from email.generator import Generator
from io import BytesIO, StringIO

data = "Key: \N{SNOWMAN}\r\n\r\n"
message = Parser().parse(StringIO(data))
with open("/tmp/rfc882test", "w") as out:
    Generator(out, maxheaderlen=0).flatten(message)
```

Fails with `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2603' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: the example is python 3 only. The real code reads from a file, and but the error is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your data is not a valid RFC2822 header, which I suspect misleads you. It's a Unicode string, but RFC2822 is always only ASCII. To have non-ASCII characters you need to encode them with a character set and either base64 or quoted-printable encoding.

Hence, valid code would be this:

```
from email.parser import Parser
from email.generator import Generator
from io import BytesIO, StringIO

data = "Key: =?utf8?b?4piD?=\r\n\r\n"
message = Parser().parse(StringIO(data))
with open("/tmp/rfc882test", "w") as out:
    Generator(out, maxheaderlen=0).flatten(message)
```

Which of course avoids the error completely.

The question is how to generate such headers as `=?utf8?b?4piD?=` and the answer lies in the [email.header](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) module.

I made this example with:

```
>>> from email import header
>>> header.Header('\N{SNOWMAN}', 'utf8').encode()
'=?utf8?b?4piD?='
```

To handle files that have a `Key: Value` format the email module is the wrong solution. Handling such files are easy enough without the email module, and you will not have to work around the restrictions of RF2822. For example:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import io
import sys
if sys.version_info > (3,):
    def u(s): return s
else:
    def u(s): return s.decode('unicode-escape')

def parse(infile):
    res = {}
    payload = ''

    for line in infile:
        key, value = line.strip().split(': ',1)
        if key in res:
            raise ValueError(u("Key {0} appears twice").format(key))
        res[key] = value
    return res

def generate(outfile, data):
    for key in data:
        outfile.write(u("{0}: {1}\n").format(key, data[key]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ensure roundtripping:
    data = {u('Key'): u('Value'), u('Foo'): u('Bar'), u('Frötz'): u('Öpöpöp')}
    with io.open('/tmp/outfile.conf', 'wt', encoding='UTF8') as outfile:
        generate(outfile, data)

    with io.open('/tmp/outfile.conf', 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as infile:
        res = parse(infile)

    assert data == res
```

That code took 15 minutes to write, and works in both Python 2 and Python 3. If you want line continuations etc that's easy to add as well.

[Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576996-rfc-822-style-parser/) is a more complete one that supports comments etc.

Comment: `s/an encoding/rfc 2047 encoding/` to avoid ambiguity with a [character] encoding.

Comment: call `'\N{SNOWMAN}'.decode('unicode-escape')` on Python 2.x  (the OP wants Python 2 compatibility).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Well, it should be `header.Header(u'\N{SNOWMAN}', 'utf8').encode()` in Python 2.

Comment: I assume it to be used in a "single source compatibility for 2.x/3.x" code i.e., `u''` fails on 3.0-3.2. For example, `u = lambda s: s.decode('unicode-escape') if isinstance(s, bytes) else s` and then `u('\N{SNOWMAN}')` in the code.

Comment: I'm asking for rfc822 /style/ headers. My file format allows utf8 and I'm reusing the email module to manipulate it.

Comment: @joeforker: Well, an RFC822 /style/ header can only contain ASCII. What you mean is you have a file format in the form of `Keyword: Data`. Reading and manipulating that is quite trivial, you don't need a module for it. The email module is for handling emails.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: He doesn't specify what technique to use for the compatibility, if he uses 2to3 or not, so I don't include that in my answer. Besides he can easily find that elsewhere on SO.

Comment: the Python 2 email module handles non-ASCII perfectly here by working with bytes. The python 3.3 module handles it with a policy object. Whither 3.2?

Comment: @joeforker: I maintain that using the email module to handle this is just adding extra useless complexity. `line.split(': ', 1)` is all you need. No policy object needed. The email module is as is documented, for creating and parsing *emails*. You are doing something simple in a  complicated and brittle way.

Comment: There's also the matter of multi-line values. The e-mail module is very easy to use and not at all brittle. http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.policy.html was introduced in Python 3.3 for this exact use case.

Comment: @joeforker: Multi-line values = line continuations, which I mentioned above. That's also a simple issue. Now if you want something that includes Mime-blocks etc, then it would make sense I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A useful solution comes from http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-October/104409.html :

```
from email.parser import Parser
from email.generator import BytesGenerator

# How do I get surrogateescape from a BytesIO/StringIO?
data = "Key: \N{SNOWMAN}\r\n\r\n" # write this to headers.txt
headers = open("headers.txt", "r", encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape")
message = Parser().parse(headers)
with open("/tmp/rfc882test", "wb") as out:
    BytesGenerator(out, maxheaderlen=0).flatten(message)
```

This is for a program that wants to read and write a binary `Key: value` file without caring about the encoding. To consume the headers as decoded text without being able to write them back out with `Generator()`, `Parser().parse(open("headers.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8"))` should be sufficient.